# Openni and Kinect on Hydro, OSX 10.8

Tags: ros, openni, ros-hydro, osx, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe I have a clean install of Hydro on my OS X 10.8. This I did through Hydro tutorial for OSX.
I did the Desktop-Full Install through `rosinstall_generator desktop_full --rosdistro hydro --deps --wet-only --tar > hydro-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall` and Hence built the packages.

I see that the "openni" stack is missing and I cannot run commands like
`roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`

I also installed openni later through `brew install openni` and below is the info of that.

```
openni: stable 1.5.7.10, devel 1.5.8.5, HEAD
http://www.openni.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/openni/1.5.7.10 (1614 files, 33M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/openni.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: automake ✔, libtool ✔, doxygen ✔
Required: libusb ✔
==> Options
--universal
    Build a universal binary
--devel
    install development version 1.5.8.5
--HEAD
    install HEAD version
```

After installing openni from brew, I built all the packages again. But still the openni stack is missing.

Now that openni is installed from brew, I followed the instructions @william has suggested me.

I did the following :

```
$ mkdir ~/openni_ws
$ cd ~/openni_ws
$ source /path/to/hydro/install/setup.bash
$ rosinstall_generator openni_launch --deps --exclude RPP --tar > openni-hydro.rosinstall
$ wstool init src -j8 openni-hydro.rosinstall
```

When I ran this : `rosdep install --from-paths ./src --ignore-src -y`, I got the following error.

```
openni_camera: No definition of [libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev] for OS [osx]
```

Hence I did the following command :

```
rosdep install --from-paths ./src --ignore-src -y --skip-keys "libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev libopenni-dev"
```

After this I did `catkin_make install` and got an error stream from which I inferred that is is not able to find the libopenni library, which I installed through brew already(as explained in first part).

```
-- checking for module 'libopenni'
--   package 'libopenni' not found
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:279 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
```

(Gist to error stream : https://gist.github.com/karthikkovalam/41ab44e53283390646be)

I did brew unlink and link as well to make sure the openni that I installed from brew is properly linked.

I want to use my kinect through openni stack on ROS. This generally comes by default in Ubuntu. Could someone explain how I can do it on my Machine with OS X 10.8. I am really looking forward to his since the whole of my work depends on Kinect based TurtleBot navigation.

**POST EDIT :**

After @demmeln suggested the procedure, I get an error that I believe is related to the compiler somehow. After I do `catkin_make install` , I get the following errors : (I am running xcode 5.1 at present and OSX 10.8). I am not clear on how to solve this.

```
Source space: /Users/Siva/openni_ws/src
Build space: /Users/Siva/openni_ws/build
Devel space: /Users/Siva/openni_ws/devel
Install space: /Users/Siva/openni_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/Users/Siva/openni_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make install -j4 -l4" in "/Users/Siva/openni_ws/build"
####
[  6%] Built target openni_camera_gencfg
[ 86%] Built target openni_driver
[ 93%] Built target openni_node
Linking CXX shared library /Users/Siva/openni_ws/devel/lib/libopenni_nodelet.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "log4cxx::Level::getWarn()", referenced from:
      openni_camera::DriverNodelet::onInitImpl() in driver.cpp.o
  "log4cxx::Level::getError()", referenced from:
      openni_camera::DriverNodelet::onInitImpl() in driver.cpp.o
  "log4cxx::Level::getFatal()", referenced from:
      openni_camera::DriverNodelet::onInitImpl() in driver.cpp.o
  "log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(char const*)", referenced from:
      openni_camera::DriverNodelet::onInitImpl() in driver.cpp.o
  "log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrBase::~ObjectPtrBase()", referenced from:
      log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Logger>::~ObjectPtrT() in driver.cpp.o
      log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Level>::~ObjectPtrT() in driver.cpp.o
  "typeinfo for log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrBase", referenced from:
      typeinfo for log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Logger> in driver.cpp.o
      typeinfo for log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Level> in driver.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [/Users/Siva/openni_ws/devel/lib/libopenni_nodelet.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [openni_camera/CMakeFiles/openni_nodelet.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158546/openni-and-kinect-on-hydro,-osx-10.8/) by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-04-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-04-30**:
Well it is not finding `openni`, but I don't know why. You can also try libfreenect.

**Comment by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on 2014-04-30**:
The openni libraries are installed at `/usr/local/Cellar/openni/1.5.7.10`. Is this creating a problem by any chance ? Should I modify any environment variable? Is the CMakeLists.txt going wrong some where? I installed freenect anyways but I need Openni for openni_launch on ros. Kindly Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to what @William proposes, here are some additional steps needed to get this working. I have submitted pull requests for according patches.

1. <s>the openni formula has a typo in the pkg-config file path: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/pull/882</s>
2. openni_camera needs a patch to compile: https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera/pull/22
3. <s>rosdep keys are missing: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/4264</s>

*EDIT*: Faults 1 and 3 have been fixed upstream. So the only additional step on top of William's instructions should the openni_camera patch.

Instructions with additional steps until the above fixes are in (which let me successfully compile on OS X 10.9):

```
mkdir ~/openni_ws
cd ~/openni_ws
source /path/to/hydro/install/setup.bash
rosinstall_generator openni_launch --deps --exclude RPP --tar > openni-hydro.rosinstall
wstool init src -j8 openni-hydro.rosinstall
rosdep install --from-paths ./src --ignore-src -y --skip-keys "libopenni-dev libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev"

# manually install the dependencies
brew install openni totakke/openni/sensor-kinect

# manually fix the typo in openni
cd /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
ln -s ../pkg-config/libopenni.pc

# apply patch to openni_camera
pushd src/openni_camera
curl https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera/pull/22.patch | patch -p1
popd

# now proceed building
catkin_make install
source ./install/setup.bash
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

**EDIT 2:** (in respose to your updated question)

> I did the following :
>
> ```
> ...
> $ source /path/to/hydro/install/setup.bash
> ...
> ```

When following the instructions, please make sure you actually replace the path in `source /path/to/hydro/install/setup.bash` with the actual path to where you installed hydro.

> When I ran this : `rosdep install --from-paths ./src --ignore-src -y`, I got the following error.
>
> ```
> openni_camera: No definition of [libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev] for OS [osx]
> ```

This indicates the rosdep database is out of date. Make sure to `rosdep update` beforehand. The `--skip-keys` is useful to make rosdep continue, but you have to make sure you install the dependencies by hand, in this case `brew install openni totakke/openni/sensor-kinect` (after `update` rosdep should be able to install them for you).

> I did brew unlink and link as well to make sure the openni that I installed from brew is properly linked.

I have outlined in my instructions why this happened and how to fix it with a manual link. The homebrew formula is updated no, so if you do `brew update` and then `brew uninstall openni` and then `brew install openni` there should not be the need for manually creating a link.

> After @demmeln suggested the procedure, I get an error that I believe is related to the compiler somehow.

What does `rosdep check --from-paths ./src --ignore-src` output (after you updated rosdep)? What does `brew info gcc` output?

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-05-13**:
You might not actually need the sensor-kinect formula... at least not to compile it seems.

**Comment by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on 2014-05-13**:
I will try this soon. Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-05-13**:
On 10.8 you might not even need the openni_camera patch, but it shouldn't hurt.

**Comment by [anaderi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18496/anaderi/) on 2014-05-26**:
works on OS X 10.9

**Comment by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on 2014-05-28**:
@demmeln Edited the question with the new errors (after post edit). Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The openni drivers are not provided by default on Ubuntu and are not part of "desktop_full". I think you will want the `openni_camera` and `openni_launch` packages:

```
$ mkdir ~/openni_ws
$ cd ~/openni_ws
$ source /path/to/hydro/install/setup.bash
$ rosinstall_generator openni_launch --deps --exclude RPP --tar > openni-hydro.rosinstall
$ wstool init src -j8 openni-hydro.rosinstall
$ rosdep install --from-paths ./src --ignore-src -y
$ catkin_make install
$ source ./install/setup.bash
$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

Another option (for the Kinect) is the libfreenect stack.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-04-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on 2014-04-29**:
After the `rosdep install --from-paths ./src --ignore-src -y` command, I get the following error.
`openni_camera: No definition of [libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev] for OS [osx]`
What do I do ?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-04-29**:
That means rosdep doesn't know how to install `libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev` for OS X. It maybe that installing `brew install openni` is sufficient, but I'm not sure. You can add a `--skip-keys libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev` to the `rosdep` command to try and continue without it.

**Comment by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on 2014-04-30**:
@william : Updated the question with new errors.